# XCode 4.2 NSArray database for tableview

Tags: iphone, database, xcode, uitableview, nsarray

I'm a beginner i have some problem with NSArray.

I created an array and add an new object(dataclass) to the locationArray

### dataclass.m

```
@synthesize UniqueID,name, address, latitude, longitude, type;

+ (id)LocationWithID:(NSString *)UniqueID name:(NSString *)name address:(NSString *)address latitude:(NSString *)latitude longitude:(NSString *)longitude type:(NSString *)type
{
    agilentLocation *newLocation = [[self alloc] init];
    newLocation.UniqueID = UniqueID;
    newLocation.name = name;
    newLocation.address = address;
    newLocation.latitude = latitude;
    newLocation.longitude = longitude;
    newLocation.type = type;
    return newLocation;
}
```

### Table.m

```
NSMutableArray *LocationArray;

[LocationArray addObject:[dataclass LocationWithID:UniqueID name:name address:address latitude:latitude longitude:longitude type:type]];
```

I would like to ask how could I call the value under my dataclass. For example I need to call the name under the dataclass for my table title.

Normally when i'm building a table i'll use

```
cell.textLabel.text = [LocationArray objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];
```

but in this case there is only one object which is "dataclass" but it has several objects under it.
how should i display the name on the table.

The code below is used to print out values for the object(dataclass)

```
for (dataclass *theLocation in LocationArray) {
    NSLog(@"Name: %@ Address: %@ Latitude: %g Longitude: %g Type :%@", theLocation.name, theLocation.address ,[theLocation.latitude doubleValue], [theLocation.longitude doubleValue], theLocation.type);
}
```

### Screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// First Return The Number of Sections.
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)iTableView {
    NSInteger aSectionCount = 0;        
    return aSectionCount;
}


// Now return the No Of Rows. In your case the total count of DataClass in LocationArray
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)iTableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)iSection {
    NSInteger aRowCount = 0;
    aRowCount = [LocationArray count];
    return aRowCount;
}


// Now for the respective Row, Pick the DataClass from Location Array and display the name.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)iTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)iIndexPath {
    NSInteger theRow = iIndexPath.row;
    NSInteger theSection = iIndexPath.section;

    NSString *aCellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell-%d-%d-%d", theSection, theRow, iTableView.tag];
    UITableViewCell *aCell = (UITableViewCell *)[iTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:aCellIdentifier];
    if (aCell == nil) {
        aCell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:aCellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    dataclass *theLocation = [LocationArray objectAtIndex:theRow];

    aCell.TitleLabel.Text = theLocation.name;

    return aCell;
}
```

Please Note that the LocationArray should be a class variable. Public or Private based on your convenience.

Hope this is what you are looking for...

Comment: Thanks! Yup this is what i want :)